# Jwt Based Role Based Authentication and Authorization in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, permissions, jwt, roles

I was designing a system where the user can have three roles admin, supervisor, and customer, and based on the role user can access a particular state, city, and street in the spring boot application. Each role type can only access the state, city, or county they are assigned. For example, a user in Washington State with an admin role can only access Washington State and all the cities and streets inside Washington and cannot access another state. I would be happy if anyone can help me with how this can be implemented in the spring boot database model and spring boot implementation to check whenever user login they will have access only for the address they are assigned.
I tried to use Jwt. Then every time the user login first I have to check the address of the user then check the role of the user. Finally, I tried to filter every request based on the role of the user.